# Is it possible to define a template region to not cache when using Twig?

Tags: php, templates, twig

I am searching for a way to define a region or block within a template that Twig will not cache.

For an example of where this would be used:

On a website that shows a list of results after a search, there is a region of filters. Each filter is saved as a session and when the document is not cached the filter values match the session.

Enabling Twig caching prevents this feature from working, but if it was possible to specify a region to not cache, I could exclude the filter area the site would function properly.

Is this possible with Twig?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of caching are you using? ESI caching allows you to give different caching rules to different parts of your template, so if you use this you can define which areas should be cached and which should not: http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/http_cache.html#edge-side-includes

If you're unfamiliar with ESI caching, KNP have made a handy tutorial: http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/new-symfony-2.2/fragments-esi-caching